# SSL communication between Java and C# applications

Tags: c#, java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

My goal is to make a secure communication between a Java server and client written in C#.

java server code:

```
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","cert/mySrvKeystore");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","myPassword");

  SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
            (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
  SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =  = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(2389);

    while(true) {
    System.err.println("server w8 new connection");
     try {

            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
            //sslsocket.startHandshake();

            in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
            out.flush();

            String response = new String(receiveMessage());
            while (response != "end") {
                System.out.println("Server recv="+response);
                response = new String(receiveMessage());
                sendMessage(("echo="+response).getBytes());
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and client written in c# :

```
        client = new TcpClient() { SendTimeout = 5000, ReceiveTimeout = 5000 };
        IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(host), port);

        client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
        client.NoDelay = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

        // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, ValidateServerCertificate, null);
        // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("someName");
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", error.Message);
            if (error.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", error.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            client.Close();
            return;
        }

        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        SendData(ascii.GetBytes("Hello World"));
```

and

```
    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
          object sender,
          X509Certificate certificate,
          X509Chain chain,
          SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

        // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
        return false;
    }
```

and i get the following errors: in c#

```
 A first chance exception of type "System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException" occurred in System.dll
 Certificate error: RemoteCertificateChainErrors
 Exception: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
 Authentication failed - closing the connection.
```

I know that the issue can be the fact that i use different types of certificates, but i don't know how to make a standard sslServerSocket with X509Certificate in java. Can some one help me, with good example, or some advice how can i reach my goal ?

P.S. I was looking to bouncycastle library, causes it has both java, and c# implementation, but i would like to use standard libraries, and built-in functionality of the languages.

Comment: This is kind of similar to another question on StackOverflow, however I can't post comments Question: [x509 Creating a certificate without BouncyCastle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle) And here is a link found on the page which describes how to do it:[Creating an x509 Certificate in Java](http://bfo.com/blog/2011/03/08/odds_and_ends_creating_a_new_x_509_certificate.html)

Comment: thanks, this really helped me to generate X509 Certificate, but how can i now bundle this to SSLServerSocket in java ?

Comment: @ry8806, I'm not sure how this helps here, since there doesn't seem any requirement for generating a certificate within the application itself. Using a tool (e.g. `keytool`) should be much easier.

Comment: Ah, [memories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719556/c-sharp-client-connecting-to-a-java-server-over-ssl). (One of my first questions on SO)

Comment: @savionok i think this link might help you combining the x509 with the SSLServerSocket, its a small code example but it should help you on your way [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/HTTPSServerAuthentication.htm)

Comment: Actually I want to do this the other way around. C# server with an android client. How can I create the self signed ssl certificates for both the C# server and the android client? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it doesn't look like you need to generate your certificate and private key programmatically. You can generate a certificate in your server keystore with `keytool`:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.jks -dname "CN=www.example.com"
```

Or better, with the SAN extension too, if you're using Java 7's `keytool`:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.jks -dname "CN=www.example.com" -ext san=dns:www.example.com
```

Here, `www.example.com` is the host name as seen by the client. You can add other things in the Subject DN (`dname`), but make sure the `CN` is the host name.

Once it's generated, export your self-signed certificate using:

```
keytool -export myservercert.crt -alias myalias -keystore mykeystore.jks
```

You should then be able to import it as a trusted certificate in your Windows certificate store from use from C#.

Comment: Why would you ever need to generate your certificate private key programmatically? Who would trust it?

Comment: @EJP agreed, it's not of much use. It could be handy if you write a "MITM proxy" (like Fiddler or [Squid's SslBump](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump)) where you would import the proxy's CA cert into your browser but generate a new cert on the fly for the requested host.

Comment: thank you ! exporting jks to crt, and importing this crt in OS as a Trusted Certificate solved my problem !